# Magento Shopping Cart payment method step, post CC details to payment gateway endpoint?

Tags: php, html, magento, payment-gateway, shopping-cart

In the Magento Shopping cart's payment method step, in the implemented payment method when the Credit Card (CC) details are entered the form does not get posted after placing the order.

The implemented payment method is setup so that the form has a action attribute pointing to a payment processor gateway and includes input fields for CC details. The name set for input fields are recognized by the endpoint accepting POST requests.

The form.phtml is setup so that the standard Magento CC input fields are surrounded by a form tag with the endpoint for the action. I do not have a submit button within this form, I thought the place order button does the submission.

**How can I get the form to submit the CC details to the endpoint once payment method selection is continued and the placed order button is clicked?**

The CC details should only be posted to the endpoint, it should not be posted to the server hosting the Magento Shopping cart.

Answer (score 1):

We would need to know more such as what the Payment module is (name, version, developer), what version of Magento you are working with and have you made any modifications to the module and core code.

This thread should answer at least some of your questions - 
[Magento Payment flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366551/magento-payment-flow)

If you want to post CC details to the endpoint, you should contact them about whether they have either:

- A payment module for Magento that you can use (only use over SSL)
- An iframe payment window that can be used

As long as you're using strong SSL certificates you can post the CC details back to the server. Magento will handle the card authorization and payments without storing any details (unless you use the 'Credit Card' payment method).

Comment: Magento version is 1.8.1. I would like to know generally for a payment module what would be the best way to post CC details to the endpoint. Assume that the model, block and templates for the payment module are already setup with Magento. I have a choice to use AJAX/iframe payment window. But I thought to post the CC details from the form in payment method step one can simply surround the default form.phtml of magento with a form tag with action to the endpoint. But doesn't seem to work. Would iframe payment window be the only best choice?

Comment: The payment gateway would handle the card auth and transaction ID generation. So the order amount, etc details will be posted to the payment gateway to generate a transaction ID. Then CC details will be posted to the payment gateway with the transaction ID to do auth & capture. I don't want Magento to handle the card auth. So would be using the Credit Card payment method.

Comment: As I said before, as long as you're using strong SSL certificates (as you should be during checkout), posting information to Magento to then post onto the endpoint is fine because Magento won't store any credit card information unless you tell it to. I've made American Express payment gateways in Magento before, and they have a 2 step process - do pre-auth to see if the credit card can be used and is valid and then do transaction. What is the bank/merchant you're trying to use or get payments from?

Comment: Also, are you using a payment method off the shelf or have you made one? It sounds like you've made one but the post/javascript isn't working correctly, or you've modified an existing one.