# What is a "Gateway"? (in the context of Magento payment)

Tags: magento, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment

I'm working on implementing a new payment methods for an e-commerce system (in the context of Magento). However, I don't fully understand what differentiate a gateway and non-gateway payment methods.

In magento, every payment method will have to inherit [`Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Payment/Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract.html). And that class has a variable called [`$_isGateway`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Payment/Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract.html#isGateway). The only cases where this variable is `true` is only for [`Mage_Paypal_Model_Direct`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Paypal/Mage_Paypal_Model_Payflowpro.html#var$_isGateway) and [`Mage_Paypal_Model_Payflowpro`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Paypal/Mage_Paypal_Model_Payflowpro.html#var$_isGateway).

The way I understand a gateway is any payment via 3rd party and payment is not transfered directly to the merchant, is it correct? How do I know if my payment methods is a gateway or non-gateway? (or in the context of Magento)

### Update Possible Answer

It seems that `$_isGateway` in Magento does nothing. Here's the [search in the source code](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%24_isGateway)

Comment: I am also trying to understand how this `$_isGateway` links with the concept of [*authorize* and *capture*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366551/magento-payment-flow).

Comment: Someone know Magento please. If you think it's too broad, mind elaborate. Because the question seems to be very simple. Is it gateway or not?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Magento, `$_isGateway` is used in multiple area. Here are the list of them:

- [`isGateway()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=isGateway%28%29&type=Code)
- [`isGatewayUsed()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=isGatewayUsed%28%29&type=Code)

The source code is self explanatory (the function name is very clear), thus also explained how a gateway differs with the non gateway. Such as the invoice, the API payment, etc...